# Caching aggregrates that are needed for sorting in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, caching, redis

As an example, consider an application with 2 MySQL tables: posts and comments. I want to fetch the posts ordered by the latest comment time. If there are lots of comments per post, this will be slow. I want to cache each post's latest comment's time somewhere.

If I cache the latest comment time for each post in Redis, then I can't use it for sorting in MySQL. Here are the approaches I can think of:

1. Add a "latest comment time" column to the posts table, then update this column whenever a new comment is created (could have performance issues because MySQL locks the row)
2. Create new table with only the post ID and latest comment time, then update this table whenever a new comment is created (need to join with main posts table)
3. Store the tuple (latest comment time, post ID) in Redis Sorted Sets, then fetch the post IDs from Redis (if I have a lot of conditions in the `where` clause, it'll be hard to represent these conditions in Redis)

My main concern is the frequency of updating the latest comment time. Even if I batched it (e.g. update each post at most once per minute), it could still be slow.

Which of these methods is "good" or "bad"? Are there better methods?

Comment: What are the actual queries you need to execute?  Have you looked into indexing your tables?

Comment: Is the query restricted to a single `user`?  Does the `Comments` table have `user_id` in it?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.

Answer (score 0):

**Latest comment for each post for one user:**

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM ( SELECT post_id, MAX(dt) AS last_comment_dt
               FROM Comments
               WHERE user_id = ? 
               GROUP BY post_id ) AS x
    JOIN Posts AS p  USING(post_id)
    ORDER BY last_comment_dt DESC
```

Index:

```
Comments:  INDEX(user_id, post_id, dt)
```

**Latest comment for each post:**

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM ( SELECT post_id, MAX(dt) AS last_comment_dt
               FROM Comments
               GROUP BY post_id ) AS x
    JOIN Posts AS p  USING(post_id)
    ORDER BY last_comment_dt DESC
```

Index:

```
Comments:  INDEX(post_id, dt)
```

Comment: Assume we're going through all the posts, this is going through every single comment for every single post

Comment: I really need to see the `CREATE TABLEs` so I can understand the relationships between users, posts, and comments.  In some schema designs, a "comment" is a special case of a "post".